# Ruby: getting disk usage information on Linux from /proc (or some other way that is non-blocking and doesn't spawn a new process)

Tags: ruby, linux

Context:

I'm on Linux. I am writing a disk usage extension for Sensu. Extensions must be non-blocking, because they are included in the agent's main code loop. They also must be very lightweight, because they may be triggered as often as once every 10 seconds, or even down to once per second.

So I cannot spawn a new executable to gather disk usage information. From within Ruby, I can only do stuff like File.open() on /proc and /sys and so on, read the content, parse it, file.close(), then print the result. Repeat.

I've found the sys-filesystem gem, which appears to have everything I need. But I'd rather not force extensions to depend on gems, if it can be avoided. I'll use the gem if it turns out to be the best way, but is there a good alternative? Something that doesn't require a ton of coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information can be accessed via the system call `statfs`

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html

I can see there is a ruby interface to this here:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/File/Statfs.html

Comment: The question now is how to get a list of all existing volumes. I guess I could parse /etc/fstab for that.

Comment: /proc/mounts - see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24182/how-to-get-the-complete-and-exact-list-of-mounted-filesystems-in-linux